# I can't start Windows Explorer without administrative privileges

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, administrator, tasks

I can't start File Explorer Task without administrative privileges in Windows 8, but if I start it with admin privileges, I can't open Windows 8 Apps, and it shows:

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to kill `explorer.exe`, but be able to safely restart it. I had success using [Process Explorer](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip) by SysInternals, now part of Microsoft.

After I killed it, it tried to restart poorly. I killed it again then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to get Task Manager and then selected New Task from the upper left menu. After a lot of flickering, eventually everything fell into place.

I use Classic Shell to replace the Start Menu and it took about 10 seconds to get the unpleasant shell icon on the start menu back in place. Remember, don't select "Replace Task Manager" in Process Explorer or you won't be able to easily run a new process once `explorer.exe` is dead!

[image: Screenshot]